# Are there any big, pre-made city campaign maps?

Tags: campaign-development, maps

I'm currently looking to create my first pbp campaign, which will be steampunk horror-themed survival as they fight to escape a labyrinthine underground city, but I am stuck on a way to map the place and fill it with interesting rooms. Is there anyone who can point me to a really big premade 'abandoned city' campaign with a horror theme I could use as a staring point? It would help if the campaign was Pathfinder or 4e, but honestly it doesn't matter that much what system the campaign uses since all I really need are a pile of ideas, premade rooms, and a big map to use as a starting point. Can anyone help?

Comment: I'd probably use a Google image search for map *1800s Paris/London/Some other interesting city* as a starting point.

Comment: That's a great idea, thanks! I'm not sure it would work for this campaign though as I'm looking for a rats' maze designed by a lunatic rather than a logical street plan.

Comment: @Hadashi: In that case, try a Pittsburgh street plan or a map of catacombs of Paris.